# Multiple Elements to Flat String Transform

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am looking to transform multiple elements from source xml and combine them in single target string element in comma separated text.

Conditions
Source Inputs are boolean type, only if value true it should be included in target list

E.g. XML

```
<Root-Element>
<EnggTypes>
<Engg1>true</Engg1>
<Engg2>true</Engg2>
<Engg3>false</Engg3>
<Engg4>false</Engg4>
<Engg5>true</Engg5>
</EnggTypes>
</Root-Element>
```

Expected Transform

```
<Root-Element>
<RoleTypes>Role1,Role2,Role5</RoleTypes>
</Root-Element>
```

Looking to achieve same in XSL 1.0 or 2.0

I started overthinking and tried to use a variable on a target side to see if I can do some choose/when to construct the string using previous value and concatenate but seems like that will not work as variable value cannot be changed once set!

```
<xsl:variable name="roleVar">
<xsl:if test="Engg1/text()='true'">Role1</if>
<xsl:if test="Engg2/text()='true'">concat(roleVar,",",Role2)</if>
<xsl:if test="Engg3/text()='true'">concat(roleVar,",",Role3)</if>
<xsl:if test="Engg4/text()='true'">concat(roleVar,",",Role4)</if>
<xsl:if test="Engg5/text()='true'">concat(roleVar,",",Role5)</if>
</xsl:variable>
```

Any inputs appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select those elements and construct the value in one expression:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="EnggTypes">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="*[. = 'true']/concat('Role', replace(local-name(), '[^0-9]+', ''))" separator=","/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRJR/1 gives

```
<Root-Element>
<EnggTypes>Role1,Role2,Role5</EnggTypes>
</Root-Element>
```

Comment: What's the purpose for the first `<xsl:template>` element? It seems to work the same without it.

Comment: The first template is the so-called "identity" template -- it's called "identity" because it just copies over anything that matches identically, without changing it.  Without the identity template, you _shouldn't_ be getting the same results.   Using the Saxon-HE 9.6.0.7 processor, and commenting out the identity template, I get `<EnggTypes>` with the list, but no outermost `<Root-Element>` tag pair.

Comment: Thanks Martin, i was exploring templates but just not getting the right way i could implement. Sometimes a very simple mapping like this could rob your entire day if you are not super stylesheet experts, i thought i was till yesterday, but learning never stops. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

XSLT 1.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EnggTypes">
    <xsl:copy>
      <RoleTypes>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Engg')][text() = 'true']"/>
      </RoleTypes>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Engg')][text() = 'true']">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Role', substring-after(local-name(), 'Engg'))"/>

    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```